# JavaScript object shortcuts

Tags: javascript

I recently tried to write shortcuts for build-in object functions in JavaScript.

Here it is:

```
function changeit(){
    var ge = getElementsByTagName() , doc = document;
    doc.ge('div')[0].innerHTML = 'Changed';
}
```

I thoughy it would actually work but it didn't. Is there a way to make it work? I mean calling a built-in object function by a `var` name, and will it work in all browsers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `getElementsByTagName` does not exist barely. You have to access it as a property of  `document`, but even then, you have to save the reference to `document` as well:

```
var ge = document.getElementsByTagName.bind(document);
```

Or, you could save the name as a string:

```
var ge = 'getElementsByTagName';
```

Then you can do:

```
document[ge]('div')...
```

Because `obj['foo']` is equal to `obj.foo`.

Comment: that's exactly what i was looking for ! great , second time in a row you helping me! thank.

Comment: [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) is only available since ECMAScript 5 (JavaScript 1.8.5).

Answer (score 7):

This:

```
var ge = getElementsByTagName()
```

**calls** the function, or attempts to. There's no global function with that name, so it won't work. Similarly,

```
doc.ge('div')
```

attempts to find a "ge" property of "doc", which also doesn't exist; you just declared "ge" a local variable, not a property of "doc".

If you want a shorter name, just do something like this:

```
function ge(tagName) { return document.getElementsByTagName(tagName); }
```

Then you can write

```
ge('div')[0].innerHTML = 'Changed';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function changeit()
{
    var ge = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    ge[0].innerHTML = ge[0].innerHTML + ' Changed';
}
```

Test here: http://jsfiddle.net/aZAkz/1/

for the syntax of `document.getElementsByTagName` you can check here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName

Answer (score 1):

What you do in your code is, you create a variable called ge, which gets the result of getElementsByTagname(). since you are selecting attributes from the window object by default, you're actually trying to assign`window.getElementByTagName()` to the variable, but the window object doesn't have such an attribute. So you replace that.

Now the second problem, you're assigning the returned value after calling the method instead of the method object itself. so `ge = document.getElementsByTagName()` should become `ge = getElementsByTagName`

Then, you create another object, called doc, which is actually the document. But, the document doesn't have an attribute called ge, you've never made ge an attribute of the document object. Here's how I would rewrite your code:

```
function changeIt(){
    var doc = document;
    //this line works, because doc doesn't get a copy of the document object but a reference to it
    //so changing document changes doc.
    document.ge = document.getElementsByTagName;
    doc.ge('div')[0].innerHTML = 'Changed';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a variable that holds a pointer to any object property:

```
var gEBTN = document.getElementsByTagName;
var gEBI = document.getElementById;
```

When you need to use it, you need to only type `gETBN('div')...`, or `gEBI('elementId')...`. In your case:

```
function changeIt() {
    var ge = document.getElementsByTagName;

    ge('div')[0].innerHTML = 'Changed';
}
```

Several hooks can be made to avoid type long commands, object chains, and you can change its values aswell (type the excerpts below on a JS Console to see the results):

**CHANGING ON THE SAME SCOPE**

```
var originalObject = {
  deepProperty: {
    deepDeepProperty: {
      someNumber: 0,
      anotherNumber: 0,
      someString: 'String',
      anotherString: 'String',
      someArray: ['a', 'b'],
      anotherArray: ['a', 'b']
    }
  }
};
var hookA = originalObject.deepProperty;
var hookB = originalObject.deepProperty.deepDeepProperty;

hookA.siblingProperty = hookA;

hookB.someNumber = 1;
hookB.anotherNumber++;

hookB.someString = 'Strong';
hookB.anotherString.replace(/i/, 'o');

hookB.someArray = ['b', 'c'];
hookB.anotherArray.shift();
hookB.anotherArray.push('c');

console.log(originalObject);
console.log(hookA);
console.log(hookB);

console.log(hookA === originalObject.deepProperty);
console.log(hookB === originalObject.deepProperty.deepDeepProperty);
```

**CHANGING INSIDE ONE FUNCTION**

```
var originalObject = {
  deepProperty: {
    deepDeepProperty: {
      someNumber: 0,
      anotherNumber: 0,
      someString: 'String',
      anotherString: 'String',
      someArray: ['a', 'b'],
      anotherArray: ['a', 'b']
    }
  }
};

function changeOriginalObject(obj) {
  var hookA = obj.deepProperty;
  var hookB = obj.deepProperty.deepDeepProperty;

  hookA.siblingProperty = hookA;

  hookB.someNumber = 1;
  hookB.anotherNumber++;

  hookB.someString = 'Strong';
  hookB.anotherString.replace(/i/, 'o');

  hookB.someArray = [
    'b',
    'c'
  ];
  hookB.anotherArray.shift();
  hookB.anotherArray.push('c');
}

console.log(originalObject);

changeOriginalObject(originalObject);

console.log(originalObject);
```